# Migrate on-premises TFS to git on Visual Studio Online

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I have a server running Team Foundation Server 2010, and I'd like to migrate it to Visual Studio Online. If possible, I'd also like to convert each project/branch (currently using TFVC) to git so that we use that from now on from VS Online. [The official method](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/setup/migrate-team-projects-vs) for migrating TFVC to VS Online only imports TFVC solutions, not git, so as far as I understand a local conversion wouldn't be possible.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tool like [`git-tfs`](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) to convert a TFVC repository to a Git repository, but keep in mind that TFS branches are fundamentally very different than Git branches, and there is not a one-to-one mapping between the two things. Git-tfs does a pretty good job of managing simple branches, but it's not perfect.

Once you've turned your TFVC repository into a Git repository, you can just add your VSO repo as a new remote and force-push it into VSO. Easy.

Comment: Well that was easy, I was trying to make it way too difficult. Thank you!